# How to start this python image filter?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, imagefilter

am a python noob here.  I was working on a project for my class, in which we had to make an image filter.  I was able to get the two filters that are currently there (pixelate and add/remove colour) working separately, but when used together, they only both show if the pixelization is done before changing the colours.  Is there a way to make it so that they will both show in the end, no matter the order they are called? my code is below:

```
#####################################
#    Your Filters with User Input   #
#####################################

def filter2():
  print("Code for filter2")

  addr = int(input("How much red would you like to add to the image (between -255 and 255)? "))
  addg = int(input("How much green would you like to add to the image (between -255 and 255)? "))
  addb = int(input("How much blue would you like to add to the image (between -255 and 255)? "))

  pixels = img.getdata()
 
  new_pixels = []
  
  for p in pixels:
    new_pixels.append(p)
  
  location = 0
  
  while location < len(new_pixels):
   
    p = new_pixels[location]
      
    r = p[0]
    g = p[1]
    b = p[2]
      
    newr = r + addr
    newg = g + addg
    newb = b + addb
      
    new_pixels[location] = (newr, newg, newb)
      
    location = location + 1
 
  newImage = Image.new("RGB", img.size)
  
  newImage.putdata(new_pixels)

  return newImage

def filter3():
  print("Code for filter3")
  img = Image.open('image.jpg')
  setting = input("How much pixelization would you like (low, medium, or high)? ")

  if (setting == "low"):
    imgSmall = img.resize((128,128),resample=Image.BILINEAR)
    newImage = imgSmall.resize(img.size,Image.NEAREST)

  elif (setting == "medium"):
    imgSmall = img.resize((64,64),resample=Image.BILINEAR)
    newImage = imgSmall.resize(img.size,Image.NEAREST)

  elif (setting == "high"):
    imgSmall = img.resize((32,32),resample=Image.BILINEAR)
    newImage = imgSmall.resize(img.size,Image.NEAREST)

  else:
    print("Invalid setting")

  return newImage

# Creates the four filter images and saves them to our files
a = grey()
a.save("grey.jpg")
b = filter1()
b.save("filter1.jpg")
c = filter2()
c.save("filter2.jpg")
d = filter3()
d.save("filter3.jpg")


# Create the combined filter image and saves it to our files

img.save("combinedFilters.jpg")
```

I have been working on this for the longest, and any help to solving my problem would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: this was the smallest I was able to reduce the code to, while keeping an idea of what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. It is almost never necessary to post this much code, less code will make it easier to find an answer to your question.

Comment: No, you can't do it so that the order in which they are applied doesn't matter. This is because the result of each operation depends on the values of the pixels in the image to which it is being applied.

Comment: I see @martineau, thank you for the help :)

Comment: you should create functions which gets parameters - ie. `def filter2(image)` - and it should return result - `return image` - then you can use image from one function in another function without saving in file and reading it again. - ie. `result = filter2(filter1(image))`

Comment: @furas, is there a way that I can send you the full code?  It is a part of a larger assignment, and i am not sure how to incorporate what you said into the whole program.

Comment: it is basic knowledge which you should learn in any tutorial - use `def filter2(image):` instead of `def filter2():` and then you can execute it as `b = filter1()` and `c = filer2(b)` and you will send image from `filter1()` to `filter2()` and then inside `def fitler2(image)` you can use `image` to work with image - `pixels = image.getdata()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work as intended, I just had to remove the line that said "img = Image.open('image.jpg')" from the "filter3" function.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have problem with basic knowlege how to create and use function with arguments. You should find it in any tutorial.

Define function with argument - i.e. `image`

```
def filter1(image):
```

and use this variable inside function

```
def filter1(image):
    
    # ... work with variable `image` ...
    
    return image
```

and then you can run

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')

img_a = filter1(img)
```

If you the same with other functions then you can send image from one function to another.

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')

img_a = grey(img)

img_b = filter1(img_a)

img_c = filter2(img_b)

img_d = filter3(img_c)

img_d.save('combinedFilters.jpg')
```

---

```
def grey(image):

    # ... work with variable `image` ...

    return image.

def filter1(image):
    
    # ... work with variable `image` ...
    
    return image


def filter2(image):
    
    # ... work with variable `image` ...
    
    return image


def filter2(image):
    
    # ... work with variable `image` ...
    
    return image

# --- main ---

img = Image.open('image.jpg')

img_a = grey(img)
#img_a.save("grey.jpg")

img_b = filter1(img_a)
#img_b.save("filter1.jpg")

img_c = filter2(img_b)
#img_c.save("filter2.jpg")

img_d = filter3(img_c)
img_d.save("filter3.jpg")
```

or you can write it shorter

```
img = Image.open('image.jpg')

img_d = filter3(filter2(filter1(grey(img))))

img_d.save("filter3.jpg")
```

---

BTW: if you run filters in different order then you may get the same result or different result - all depend how filters works.

Comment: for this assignment, I can only edit what is under the "Your filter" and "Your filters with user input" comments.  Is there a way that I could send you the full code for more context?

Comment: but all your code is in under "Your filter" and "Your filters with user input"  - so I don't see problem. And there is no sense to send full code. If you need help then put all in question.